# css glow effect com CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Neste site
https://nestpowerproject.withgoogle.com/
há um efeito de glow muito interessante; não sei se será feito com CSS
Alguém saberá dar-me algumas dicas sobre como fazer aquilo?
Grato

Comment: Para mim, esse site só abre uma tela que, exceto por um logotipo discreto e uns botões bem simples nos cantos, é completamente preta. Não vi nenhum efeito de glow lá.

Comment: O efeito não é com CSS, é OpenGL ou WebGL.

Answer (score 3):

O efeito do sei muito provavelmente é com script, não achei referencias no CSS que se aproximem do efeito que está na tela. Acredito que tenha sido feito com `canvas`.

***Para quem não conseguiu visualizar essa é a imagem retirada do site de exemplo.***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com CSS usando `linear-gradiente`, e `filter:blur` e `@keyframes` vc consegue algo bem próximo.

```css
html, 
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%), url(http://unsplash.it/300/180);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
        .glow {
      position: relative;
      width: 200px;
      height: 205px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%), url(http://unsplash.it/300/180);
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-size: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
    .glow::after, 
    .glow::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, orangered, yellow, green, blue, purple, magenta);
      background-size: 400%;
      top: -2px;
      left: -2px;
      width: calc(100% + 4px);
      height: calc(100% + 4px);
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: -1;
      animation: anima 20s infinite linear, gira 20s infinite linear;
    }
    .glow::after {
      filter: blur(20px);
      border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
      opacity: .8;
    }
    @keyframes anima {
      0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
      }
      50% {
        background-position: 400% 0;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 0 0;
      }
    }
    @keyframes gira {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
      }
      50% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) scale(.975);
        border-radius: 47% 53% 50% 55%;
      }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);
      }
    }
    .wrapper {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 100;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">    
    <div class="glow"></div>    
</div>
```

Comment: cara vc é mt bom com css.

Comment: @hunterxhunter cara até um ano atras meu CSS era MUITO limitado, ai resolvi estudar, ver exemplos, participar aqui do StackOverflow, e tenho melhorado muito no CSS, aprendo muito aqui, além de também poder por em prática coisas que nunca tinha aplicado em outro lugar. Essa é a vantagem de colabora, pode exercitar e colocar o conhecimento e pratica, muitas vezes errando e aprendendo...! Obrigado pelo elogio :D

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl. Muitíssimo bom o exemplo :-)

Comment: @user1463905 sem problemas amigo, não é tão sofisticado quanto o do exemplo, mas é mais leve e fácil de implementar. Acho que pode te quebrar um galho. Boa sorte ai